# ProxySQL Client Connections

Tags: mysql, proxysql

When I Query ProxySQL Client Connections :

**select * from stats.stats_mysql_global where variable_name like 'Client_connection%';**

```
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_Name                       | Variable_Value |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Client_Connections_aborted          | 0              |
| Client_Connections_connected        | 495            |
| Client_Connections_created          | 43785          |
| Client_Connections_non_idle         | 495            |
| Client_Connections_hostgroup_locked | 0              |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Connections non idle is always same with connections non idle;

But when I query on Process List :

**show processlist;**

in the command fields, all status is Sleep.

The Client_Connections_non_idle must be zero, but not in my case.

What is wrong with my thought ?

Thanks for any explanation of my problems.

I am using ProxySql v2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already find the solution of my problem. Before i set `wait_timeout` too big, after I set `wait_timeout` into 30000 (30 second) it is normal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ProxySQL documentation](https://proxysql.com/documentation/stats-statistics/#:%7E:text=Client_Connections_non_idle)

```
Client_Connections_non_idle : number of client connections that are currently handled by the main worker threads. If ProxySQL isn’t running with “–idle-threads”, Client_Connections_non_idle is always equal to “Client_Connections_connected”
```

So unless you run ProxySQL with `--idle-threads` this is expected behaviour and nothing to worry about. You can read more about idle threads [in the documentation](https://proxysql.com/documentation/proxysql-threads/#!:%7E:text=idle%20threads)

Comment: But I already run ProxySQL with --idle-threads. This is my command to start proxySQL:

proxysql --idle-threads -c /var/lib/proxysql/proxy01/proxysql01.cnf